# How can I detect that someone is scanning my network?

Tags: networking, security

Suppose another person is running a network scan on the network and my computer belongs to this network.

Are there ways to find who is performing the network scan or know that a network scan is being perform on my network?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/157785/detect-computer-which-does-port-scanning . Cannot close as dupe directly, thus voting to move (then close later :-) ).

Comment: And even if it's not an exact dupe (debatable), this question is better suited to serverfault.

Comment: I can't see why it would be better suited for SF. Just connecting your computer with a network is not unique to desktop support and professional networking. This is something a home user can ask themselves as well.